# Excel: SUMPRODUCT and cells containing ""

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In cell N30 I have this formula:

`=(SUMPRODUCT(A2:B2;$A$29:$B$29)/SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:B2<>"");$A$29:$B$29))`

This is a simplified version, hopefully it still makes sense. If the cells in `A2:B2` are empty, it returns `DIV/0` which is not a problem because I have the result in another column and in the column where I want to see the results I use `=IF(ISERROR(N30);"";N30)`.

However, I would like to populate cells in `A2:B2` with data from another workbook, from cells which either have values (no problem) or are not empty but contain `“”`.

The problem I now have is that my `SUMPRODUCT` formula doesn’t see `“”` as an empty cell, but something else, and returns a VALUE error and doesn’t produce a result until all the references contain actual numbers.

My question: is there a way to make `SUMPRODUCT` see `“”` as a truly empty cell, or some other workaround you can suggest?

I hope my question is easy enough to follow. It’s quite a complicated situation involving 2 different workbooks with lots of data, so I’ve had to simplify it a lot. Hopefully, it still makes sense.

TIA.

Comment: Yes you can do this probably using in this way: `IF(ISERR(--A2:B2),0,A2:B2)` so the whole formula becomes: `=SUMPRODUCT((IF(ISERR(--A2:B2);0;A2:B2))*$A$29:$B$29)/SUMPRODUCT((IF(ISERR(--A2:B2);0;A2:B2))*$A$29:$B$29)` because `""` doesn't produce a character code and certainly returns an error, so you can parse this error using the above

Comment: Small "coding" technique, consider trapping the error first probably something like: `IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1:B1)),...,"")`. This avoids trapping it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in Excel there is no way that the result of any formula is treated by other formulas as a blank cell. It can be treated as the number 0 or empty text at best.
If we are going to perform calculations, it would be better to use the number `0`. A function that acts as a number filter in Excel is the `N` function. If its argument is text, it returns `0`, if it is a logical value – it returns `1` or `0`, respectively. Numbers remain unchanged. Unfortunately, it is not immune to errors.
There is a problem with using this function with cell ranges. If the argument to `N` is a range that spans more than 1 cell, it returns the result only for the first cell of that range. The workaround is to precede the range with a `+` sign or use some other operation to convert the range to an array.
In this example, the notation `N(+A2:B2)` should be used.